# Selecting only one minimum value by expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, qgsexpression, min

If there are two values that are equal and minimum, the minimum function in "Select by expression" returns both of them.

Is there any way to select by expression only one of them? If not, how to delete these repeated values, since I need only one minimum value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_first(array_agg($id, filter:=min("your field"))) = $id
```

It creates an array of all feature ids having the minimum value and only selects the first one. You can also use other methods than [`array_first()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#array-first) or do some calculations and tweakings on this if you want.

Comment: That works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is:

```
id = array_get(array_sort(array_agg(id,filter:=value=minimum (value))),0)
```

Explanation: get an array of all `id` values where `value` field is the minimum. Sort the array ascending and get the first `id` value.

[image]

Comment: IMHO your solution is much identical as one provided by @MrXsquared, because `array_get(..., 0)` is the same as `array_first(...)` and the same as `array(...)[0]`. By the way `array_sort(...)` does not really needed, I am not sure whether the OP needs a feature with the lowest `id`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)